# Getting screenshot of background windows

Tags: macos, bash, background, screenshot

Is it possible to make a screenshot of non-foreground windows?

In my case I have several windows stacked and I'd like to get a screenshot of all of them separately. I would like to be able to do something like: make screenshot of layer 3 of 10, and get a screenshot of the third window of the pile.

I'd like it to be done in bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screencapture -l` captures a window by ID:

`i=1; for l in $(osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to id of windows where visible is true' | tr -d ,); do screencapture -l$l /tmp/$((i++)).png; done`

`window 2 where visible is true` is usually the second frontmost window. Some applications like Chrome don't support getting the IDs with AppleScript, but see these questions:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56561
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73994